# combinatoric proof $\sum_{i=0}^{n}(-1)^i\binom{n}{i}\binom{n-i+k-1}{k}=\binom{k-1}{k-n}$

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, binomial-coefficients

I would like help with combinatorial proof ,
not algebraic proof . Thank you for your time

$\sum_{i=0}^{n}(-1)^i\binom{n}{i}\binom{n-i+k-1}{k}=\binom{k-1}{k-n}$

Comment: A question on [math.se]: [Proving $\binom {n-1}{r-1}=\sum_{k=0}^r(-1)^k\binom r k \binom{n+r-k-1}{r-k-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1234684). I found it [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bi%3D0%7D%5E%7Bn%7D(-1)%5Ei%5Cbinom%7Bn%7D%7Bi%7D%5Cbinom%7Bn-i%2Bk-1%7D%7Bk%7D%3D%5Cbinom%7Bk-1%7D%7Bk-n%7D%24&p=1). Some advice on searching: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265)

Answer (score 4):

Denote $[n]=\{1,\ldots,n\}$.

We choose an $i$-subset $A\subset [n]$, then a $k$-multiset $B\subset [n]\setminus A$, and take $(-1)^i$ for each such a choice. Note that if $B$ is fixed, the sum of $(-1)^{|A|}$ over subsets $A\subset [n]\setminus B$ equals to 0 unless $B=[n]$, when the sum equals 1. Therefore we should count $k$-multisets $B$ which cover $[n]$. These are in bijection with $(k-n)$-multisets of $[n]$, there exist exactly ${k-n+(n-1)\choose k-n}={k-1\choose k-n}$ such multisets.